# Issues when HTML body element is positioned 'relative'

Tags: html, css-position, margin, document-body, getboundingclientrect

On one of the websites, I found that `body` element is set `position: relative` and the content inside body seem to be shifted downwards by a scale of `margin-top` CSS value set on the topmost element in body.

1. Why body has CSS 'position: relative' set? Is it intended to fix some bug? I heard that there was some IE bug where we were not able to set absolute positioning of elements.
2. Why 'margin-top' of 'only' the first element inside body affects the position of every element?
3. Javascript function 'getBoundingClientRect()' returns wrong value for any element as it does not consider this margin-top value set on topmost element.

Comment: Can you please create a http://jsbin.com demo so we can see what you mean? Also don't forget to add the relevant code to reproduce the issue right into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1. Why does the body have CSS 'position:relative' set? Is it intended to fix some bug? I heard that there was some IE bug where we were not able to set absolute positioning of elements.`

FC: That's not intended to fix a bug, but probably because one the (direct) children of the body element has `position:absolute`. Without the body having `position:relative`, that child would be positioned relative to the canvas (the browser inner window), rather than relative to the body element. See [this tutorial](http://www.conijnwebdesign.nl/tutorials/how-to-position-divs-with-css.php) ('Nested position:absolute') for the full story. There may have been IE bugs in that respect in the past, but as of IE8 IE behaves normally when it comes to this.

.
`2. Why does 'margin-top' of 'only' the first element inside the body affect the position of every element?`

FC: That is by design. Vertical margins affect the position of the subsequent sibling elements, a `position:relative; top:20px` does not. Again, see the mentioned tutorial for the full story.

.
`3. Javascript function 'getBoundingClientRect()' returns wrong value for any element as it does not consider this margin-top value set on topmost element.`

FC: That would also be by design, but I'm not sure whether you are interpreting matters correctly. Can you post some code to demonstrate it? What I do know is that you should be careful with that method. See [this Dottoro page](http://help.dottoro.com/ljvmcrrn.php) for the full story, including alternatives.